# Where is the [TestMethod] Attribute in TypeMock?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, typemock

Ok, dumb question. I'm trying to set up my first TypeMock demo project in VS2005 but it doesn't recognize the [TestMethod] attribute. I've included both the TypeMock and TypeMock.ArrangeActAssert assemblies and I'm referencing them with "using" statements. Even intellisense can't find the attribute. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TestMethod] is from the Visual Studio unit testing 'framework'.
The following code shows basically how to use the attribute:

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyFirstTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
    }
}
```

If you're using NUnit or another framework, the attributes are possibily different.

Answer (score 4):

Which unit testing framework are you using? `TestMethod` sounds like the [Visual Studio test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182516(VS.80).aspx) system, while the [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) counterpart is called `Test`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that the TestMethodAttribute comes from MSTest, not TypeMock.
So you should add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

Edit:
This is the namespace where the attribute is defined:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

Answer (score 3):

[TestMethod] comes from the MSTest library not from the TypeMock framework

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I was of the impression that TypeMock functioned as a complete mock/unit test framework on its own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MSTest, you must include [TestClass()] for the class and [TestMethod()] for the tests (don't know if parenthesis are needed).

TypeMock is a mocking framework, so you should worry first for what testing framework you're using.